# AVPlayer Skips the Beginning of a Video

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation, avplayer

I'm having an issue with AVPlayer skipping the first 0.5 seconds of a video I'm playing when I attempt to play it immediately after pre-rolling.

First, I create the player:

```
self.videoPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
```

Then, I add the player item to the player and add an observer to check and see when the item is ready:

```
[self.videoPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem" options:0 context:kBLCurrentPlayerItemStatusContext];
[self.videoPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:self.currentVideoPlayerItem];
```

When the player item is observed, I will check to see if the player is ready to play.  If it's not ready to play, I will add an observer to make sure it's ready to play:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
...
} else if (context == kBLCurrentPlayerItemStatusContext) {
       [self.videoPlayer removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem" context:&kBLCurrentPlayerItemStatusContext];
       if ([self.videoPlayer status]==AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
             [self prerollVideoPlayer];
       } else {
             [self.videoPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:&kBLVideoPlayerStatusContext];
       }
}
...
```

When the player status is observed as ready to play, I then preroll the player:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
...
  if (context == kBLVideoPlayerStatusContext) {
      if ([self.videoPlayer status] == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            [self.videoPlayer removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" context:&kBLVideoPlayerStatusContext];
            [self prerollVideoPlayer];
      }
}
...
```

After the pre-roll is complete, I play the player:

```
-(void)prerollVideoPlayer{
    [self.videoPlayer prerollAtRate:1.0 completionHandler:^(BOOL finished){
        if (finished) {
                [self.videoPlayer play];
        }
    }];
}
```

When the player plays in this way, it skips the first ~0.5 seconds of the video.  If I don't have the player play immediately when it's finished pre-rolling, and I call the play method later it plays fine.  I've checked to make sure all the observers are correctly observed and they occur in the order I've noted above.  Is there another observer I need to add or a notification I should check for to avoid this skipping behavior?

Comment: Are you playing multiple videos back to back? I ask because you are calling replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem. In my experience with AVPlayer I have seen it behave remarkably different when calling replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem vs killing the current AVPlayer and creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I tried that, but I got the same behavior.  I think it has something to do with the playerItem.  Even if I copy the same playerItem and reload it into the player, I still get the same delay.  I've tried observing the playerItem status as well and making sure it's ready to play in addition to the player, but that hasn't helped either.

Comment: I just added an audio track to my video. It's interesting to note that the audio of my video will play right away, but the part it skips is the video only.  I just see a black screen for the first 0.5 seconds.  But the music plays correctly.

Comment: It really sounds like the delay you're experiencing is due to the player doing its own internal buffering. Have you tried streaming a lower quality video to see if the delay is less?

Comment: You ever solve this?

Comment: If you're playing an AVComposition, make sure you minimize the number of AVMutableCompositionTracks. If you're transitioning between full screen videos (e.g. video 1, then crossfade to video 2, then crossfade to video 3), you can get by with two video tracks (e.g. video 1 and 3 on composition track 1 and video 2 on composition track 2).