# AVPlayerStatus vs AVPlayerItemStatus uses

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer

Can anyone explain the difference between AVPlayerStatus and AVPlayerItemStatus? and which one to observe using KVO for listening to status when using AVPlayer for playing videos?

Comment: The same question answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30376314/1310204